# How to automatic declare operator for class?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example, I want `operator+` to plus every field in class

```
class Test {
  final int var1;
  final int var2;
  final int var3;
  final int var4;

  Test(this.var1, this.var2, this.var3, this.var4);

  Test operator +(Test other) {
    return Test(
      var1 + other.var1,
      var2 + other.var2,
      var3 + other.var3,
      var4 + other.var4,
    );
  }
}
```

This very cumbersum and duplicated, especially when I have many fields (let say 100), I just want to add every field.

Is there other way to do this faster? Why it didn't have default `operator+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, as dart isn't a reflective language, so its code can't inspect itself.

To give you a clearer idea, here an example of what you could use, [but in Java](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html), you could probably achieve what you're trying to do with this language feature.

So, long story short, you **can't** do this in dart, at the moment.

Comment: I hope they add this function soon. I will try to generate this code by another code then.

Comment: I don't think they will, but there is something you could use to achieve this (try for example https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable), but still, i don't think it is the best way to do this, just specify every field :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to work around this.

By convert it to a map using [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) and iterate through the map

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Test {
  final int var1;
  final int var2;
  final int var3;
  final int var4;

  Test(this.var1, this.var2, this.var3, this.var4);

  factory Test.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TestFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TestToJson(this);

  Test operator +(Test other) {
    final thisJson = toJson();
    final otherJson = other.toJson();
    final Map<String, dynamic> result = {};
    for (var key in thisJson.key) {
      result[key] = thisJson[key] + otherJson[key];
    }
    return Test.fromJson(result);
  }
}
```

*Note: this code is inefficient in term of performance (it has to encode and decode JSON), so don't do this if you call this operator a lot.